# PROB30 in a TAF as an alternate still legal to use

Tags: faa-regulations, safety

Does a PROB30 in a TAF report affect your ability to use an airport as an alternate if conditions still remain above landing minima but less than alternate minima.

Example:
TAF XYZA 061335Z 0615/0715 33012KT 9999 SCT015 BKN025 TX02/0618Z TNM02/0715Z
TEMPO PROB30 0615/0703 800 -RADZ BR BKN004 OVC013
BECMG 0703/0705 03008KT
BECMG 0709/0711 CAVOK

Operating minima at Airport XYZA is 550M/200'.

Flight ETA falls within 1500/06-1500/07. Can you still use the airport as an alternate airport?

Comment: Does your question assume that you're unable to land at your destination airport and now you are enroute to your planned alternate, and then a new TAF is issued forecasting the the alternate weather to be below standard alternate mins (per FAR 91.169) but above the alternate's IAP landing mins?  And you want to know how the PROB30 weather impacts this? Also, would clarify what "Operating minima at Airport XYZA is 550M/200'" means (e.g. is 200 ft the MDA and 500M (meters) the visibility for an instrument approach at the alternate)?

Comment: Would you verify what country your question applies to?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Canadian AIM states if the PROB30/PROB40 is below alternate minima but not landing minima for the airport, you can still use the airport as an alternate. My understanding of NWS is that it doesn't use PROB40, so is this legal in the US? UK/ICELAND/GREENLAND/CANADA(verified).

Comment: The NWS (Aviation Weather Center) does issue "PROB40" TAFs.  See this link: [AWC](https://www.aviationweather.gov/taf/decoder).

Comment: I guess this source is not reliable, then:  https://training.weather.gov/nwstc/aviation/TAF/lesson4/prob30.html

Comment: Well, it seems like the two sources are in conflict. One states PROB40 can be used and the other states only PROB30  is used. I don't know why.